# two special signs separated with blanko not found by solr (e.g: ! !)

Tags: search, solr, filter, whitespace

Two special signs separated with blanko not found by solr (e.g:  ! !)
I have this index:

http://localhost:8983/solr/koolcha/get?id=547deb3649dbae548b0f0100

```
{
  "doc": {
    "status": "xxxxxx",
    "updated": "2014-12-05T09:47:27Z",
    "ns": "foo3.bags",
    "created": "2014-12-02T16:39:18Z",
    "_ts": 6.2177735253447e+18,
    "label": "_DSC0571.tif",
    "project": "xxxxx",
    "assignee": "xxxxx",
    "folderid": "! !",
    "_version_": 1.5180111153642e+18,
    "_id": "547deb3649dbae548b0f0100",
    "bagid": "xxxxx"
  }
}
```

When I try to search it by 'folderid'
[http://localhost:8983/solr/koolcha/select?q=folderid:\!%20\!](http://localhost:8983/solr/koolcha/select?q=folderid:%5C!%20%5C!)
solr do not find anything

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">0</int>
        <lst name="params">
            <str name="q">folderid:\! \!</str>
        </lst>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
</response>
```

If I put some other value it works, even with special signs e.g.'!!' will work.
Only combination of special signs with blanks return nothing.
Is this a bug in Solr? Or I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides escaping I think you have to quote the filter query:

```
 http://localhost:8983/solr/koolcha/select?q=folderid:"\! \!"
```

And use the Lucene Query parser (which you probably already do).

Comment: Yes, if you use blanks you have to double quote it. Now it works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Once you think your problem is solved satisfactorily please do not forget to mark the answer as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. Other people can see that your issue is solved and both you and the answerer will gain some reputation. You can even answer your own questions and (after some time) accept that answer. Accepting is by no means mandatory, you can also wait for more answers when you're not entirely sure.